# C99: Why does %lli not match int64_t on 64bit machines?

Tags: c, gcc, printf, c99

I'm porting 32bit ARM code to 64bit x86 and hit the following error:

```
format '%lli' expects argument of type 'long long int',
but argument 3 has type 'int64_t'
```

I found a lot info about using `PRIi64` in this case, but nothing about "why I cannot use `lli`?".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
    int64_t hugo = 993;
    long long int fred = 994;
    printf("%s -> %" PRIi64 " lli -> %lli\n", PRIi64, hugo, fred);
    return 0;
}
```

The code above compiles without error and prints `li -> 993 lli -> 994`. So why do I need `li` for int64_t (8 bytes) and `lli` for long long int (8 bytes) if both have the same size?

I found one post which says, that it's `a portability issue warning`. So it is save to turn off this warning? (The only flag I found is [`-Wno-format`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) which disable quite a lot checks...)

Comment: `lld` does not appear in your code? Please post the exact code that is producing the message.

Comment: `int64_t` is a fixed size of 8 bytes as the name implies. However, the size of `long long int` is implementation dependent.

Comment: so I would expect to get this warning, when compiling for a system where `lli` does not match the given parameter - e.g. where `lli` would expect a 128bit integer.

Comment: @Charly According to the C Standard lld doesn't match int64_t even if the underlying type is the same, so gcc is correct to warn you.

Comment: `PRIu64` should be `PRIi64`.

Answer (score 0):

When the Standard was written, many implementations had two or more integer types with the same size and representation; most typically, `int` would have the same size and representation as either `short` or `long`.

Even on platforms where the sizes and representations would match, conversion from `int*` to a `short*` or `long*` requires a cast, but on implementations which used the same representation for two (or more) types, a pointer to either could be used to access data of the other.  Support for such usage was not considered an "extension" of C, but more of a "well duh, what else would it do?" that seemed so obvious as to not require documentation(*)

The authors of gcc, however, assume that no pointer to a non-character integer type will be used to access things of any other non-character integer type--*even those whose size and representation are identical*.  Since `printf` would use a `long long int*` to read a parameter for `%lld`, a `long*` to read one for `%ld`, and an `int*` to read one for `%d`, the authors of gcc would view any attempt to use a `%lld` to process an argument of type `int64_t` as Undefined Behavior on implementations where that type is defined as something other than `long long`, even if its size and representation would be as expected.

(*)While C89 requires that all "extensions" be documented, the annex which lists common extensions doesn't list it.  Since the authors of the Standard cannot plausibly have been unaware that many--if not most--compilers have two or more integer types that share the same size and representation, and allow pointers to those types to be used interchangeably, the only reasonable conclusion would be that they did not regard such behavior as an "extension" that would require documentation.